# Connect multiple tables with a main table depending on the type and the ID

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, inner-join, join

I have a database that contains four tables. The first which called `items` table

**items**

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
    `ID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `time_created` VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
    `type` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `item_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

this table holds `Foreign Key`s in the `item_ID` column, but this column could hold the ID for any of the other three tables which every one of them has a specific type that is hold in the `type` column

**photos** *The type of this table is `1`*

```
CREATE TABLE `photos` (
    `ID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
```

**notes** *The type of this table is `2`*

```
CREATE TABLE `notes` (
    `ID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `content` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
);
```

**alarms** *The type of this table is `3`*

```
CREATE TABLE `alarms` (
    `ID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `event_time` VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
    `reminder_time` VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
);
```

Now I want to make a query to select the `items` table and join all the other three tables together depending in the `type` and the `item_ID`. And here is what I've tried so far

```
SELECT * FROM `items`
    INNER JOIN `photos`
        ON (`items`.`type`=1 AND `items`.`item_ID`=`photos`.`ID`)
    INNER JOIN `notes`
        ON (`items`.`type`=2 AND `items`.`item_ID`=`notes`.`ID`)
    INNER JOIN `alarms`
        ON (`items`.`type`=3 AND `items`.`item_ID`=`alarms`.`ID`)
```

But unfortunately, the SQLite returns 0

Comment: I'm afraid you are going to have to make two queries. One to get the type and then another to join based on the type. A generic 'items' table is not recommended. It isn't good design.

Comment: @DamienBlack the types are determined by the application (the code). Will that one of the queries? I understand about the generic table, do you have any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use union to get over this problem

```
SELECT * FROM `items`
    INNER JOIN `photos`
        ON `items`.`item_ID`=`photos`.`ID` WHERE `items`.`type`=1
UNION
SELECT * FROM `items`
    INNER JOIN `notes`
        ON  `items`.`item_ID`=`notes`.`ID` WHERE `items`.`type`=2
UNION
SELECT * FROM `items`
    INNER JOIN `alarms`
        ON  `items`.`item_ID`=`alarms`.`ID` WHERE `items`.`type`=3
```

Comment: This does not work because the tables do not have the same number of columns. And why use UNION when there will be no duplicates?

Comment: I think the query can be modified to select only necessary columns.AFAIK union is used to combine multiple result sets.

Comment: UNION removes duplicates. To just combine result sets, you would use UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0):

An INNER join will drop all records that do not match any record from the other table.
This means that your query will not return anything because there is no `items` record that could match all three joins.

You need to use [outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) to allow to return records without matches:

```
SELECT *
FROM      items
LEFT JOIN photos ON items.type = 1 AND items.item_ID = photos.ID
LEFT JOIN notes  ON items.type = 2 AND items.item_ID = notes.ID
LEFT JOIN alarms ON items.type = 3 AND items.item_ID = alarms.ID
```